# How to download dependencies using 'npm install'?

Tags: json, node.js, angular

I have a package.json file when I navigate to the folder eg: angular app(which contains package.json) and use command `npm install` it takes 10min to download just 6 dependencies what am I doing wrong why does it take so much time after finishing it downloads some 25-30 files which are not correct files. I am using windows.

```
{
      "name": "angular-2",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
        "tsc": "tsc",
        "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
        "lite": "lite-server",
        "typings": "typings",
        "postinstall": "typings install"
      },
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.13",
        "systemjs": "0.19.25",
        "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
        "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
        "zone.js": "0.6.6"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
        "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
        "typescript": "^1.8.9",
        "typings":"^0.7.11"
      }
}
```

Comment: Have you set up pre requirement ? if yes you just do `npm install` thats fine

Comment: @soorapadman I have installed node.js from its website then I installed it. After that I made new folder called angularapp on right clicking it I opened cmd so it navigates to angularapp now I type `npm install` is it correct procedure.

Comment: check this link this is what you want:https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to run this command once, dont run it again and again unless your package.json changes

Comment: I have installed node.js from its website then I installed it. After that I made new folder called angularapp on right clicking it I opened cmd so it navigates to angularapp now I type npm install is it correct procedure

Comment: you need to make package.json , 
You can do it manually or you can use command npm init
and after adding your dependencies in package.json use npm install and you are good to go. you dont need to npm install everytime

Comment: I didn't do `npm init` so when I navigate to angularapp folder which contains package.json I should open cmd then first do `npm init` then `npm install` am I right.

Comment: no npm init will make package.json for you, if you have created manually then just npm install in that folder, it will install that dependency for you

Comment: @rockstone, Good luck with npm 
and know you get basic idea how npm works right!! :)

Comment: This is really the answer he was looking for?

Comment: @WilliamHampshire He seems to be new user of npm, you I guided him how it works

Comment: I understand, but his question was asking why does it take so long to run `npm install`. He didn't give any indication that he was trying to run it over and over again... it seemed that what he was saying is that when he needed to do an npm install it was taking longer than expected (hence the reason for my answer - which is a more common question than someone just not bothering to google what npm install actually does)

Comment: @WilliamHampshire you may be right here. user to new technology is very confused and their question is very vagues. I have been through that stage for npm recently so I understood what rock stone wanted here. But his/her question is little misguided for other, but when they will read comment. they will come to know about what rock stone wanted

Answer (score 2):

Could be because you're running old versions? Try upgrading to the [latest version of node](https://nodejs.org/en/) and npm:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

or

```
npm update npm -g
```

-

Since you're on Windows, I've also heard of people using [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) which appears to be pretty good for package management on windows.

Comment: I have installed node.js from its website then I installed it. After that I made new folder called angularapp on right clicking it I opened cmd so it navigates to angularapp now I type npm install is it correct procedure

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the following command : 
     **--save-dev: Package will appear in your devDependencies.**
Consider the example to install gulp-uglify.

```
npm install gulp-uglify --save-dev
```

Comment: Permare I have installed node.js from its website then I installed it. After that I made new folder called angularapp on right clicking it I opened cmd so it navigates to angularapp now I type npm install is it correct procedure

Comment: Yes , you need to hit the npm install in that folder only once.
@rockstone its Pemare :)

Comment: I did it but after 10min it shows 25-30 folders it should only show 11 folders as I want to download only 6 dependencies.

Comment: Not necessary as there will other packages in dependcies which require some other package, which will also be installed. Like consider the angular2 package which has several dependcies on other package . Check https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2 the dependcies on right side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use yarn instead of using npm. Which is fast as compare to npm, But you are saying only 6 dependencies and it is taking 10 minutes may be the reason behind that your internet speed.

https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/getting-started/

Comment: I have installed node.js from its website then I installed it. After that I made new folder called angularapp on right clicking it I opened cmd so it navigates to angularapp now I type npm install is it correct procedure

Comment: Do you realize this is the FOURTH time you've said the exact same thing in a comment?

Comment: yes it is right procedure. for installing dependencies but if you are installing particular